# Mortar coming from hole in wall, is it bugs? (Indoors)

Tags: walls

We are currently renovating an empty house, under a gas fireplace we keep getting this mound of dirt, we have noticed a small hole in the wall under the fireplace which the dirt/mortar comes from. I've hoovered three times and it keeps coming back.
What bugs would cause this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: How long does it take for the pile to re-appear? Is it sudden or slowly builds up over time? Does it only happen when you have used the fireplace?

Comment: perfect nesting place for mice, dry and warm

Comment: It builds up over a week or so. The fireplace is a gas fire unused, the house has been empty for months

Comment: Could mice get in/out that tiny hole? We have suspected mice in the property

Answer (score 1):

It's 2022. The 21st century, even.

Take an obsolete (or not) cell phone or video camera and set it up pointing at the hole, recording video at a low enough quality or frame rate that it can record 8-12 hours worth. Leave the light on so the camera can see. Review the video the next day to see what your cause is.

Odds are good that *something* is going in and out of that hole, though you might strike out if they are just pushing material out of the hole without exposing themselves.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if this is something we can do

Answer (score 0):

The hole in the wall is possibly a cleanout for the fireplace. Look for some type of grating or cover inside the fireplace that leads to that hole. That could be buildup over time that's just falling out. There's usually a tray that fits in the hole. It's been cut square so it looks intentional. Try hoovering deep inside that hole.

Comment: It's a gas "fireplace" and seems to be hanging above a wooden baseboard over carpet, so I doubt it has a cleanout, personally. There shouldn't be anyting to clean out, and the hole seems to be into the wall, not into the "fireplace" (or room heater?)

Comment: @Ecnerwal  It's a gas fireplace now, but maybe a regular one before. Many northerners burn wood in a gas fireplace.

Comment: It's a gas fire on the wall. The fire hasn't been used for many years and the house has been empty for 7 months